# SQL Server (Transact-SQL) difference between Filestream and BLOB

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Could anyone explain in laymans terms, what is the difference between those two data types and moreso, which are the pros and cons of using either of those to store files in a database.

If context is needed then I am creating a web app, where users can upload a multitude of different data, like images, Excel files, .docx etc.

Comment: take a look at this: https://sqltales.wordpress.com/2012/05/15/varbinary-vs-filestream-and-other-blob-issues-3/

Comment: Kid, try to create a blob column populate it with a few dozem files with 1GB and try a `selec *` it will tell you everything you need to never try to do it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blobs are stored in a varbinary(MAX) column with the value stored in data pages inside the database data file(s).

With FILESTREAM, values are stored as individual files separately on the filesystem, with an individual file for each row and value. These files are managed internally by SQL Server and can be stored and retrieved using T-SQL just like normal varbinary(MAX) values or [with Win32 APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/access-filestream-data-with-opensqlfilestream).

There are also [FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server), which is a specialized table with a predefined schema on top of `FILESTREAM`. FileTables provide T-SQL access like blobs and `FILESTREAM` and can optionally be access via a SQL Server managed UNC path, similarly to a normal Windows share. Creating/deleing files via the share inserts/deletes rows from the file table and visa-versa.

Comment: Blobs are not stored in data pages (I guess that's true for very old versions) but in separate. The column only holds a pointer for the blob. Anyway putting big files in a column is a no-no unles you are using the "new" Filestream thing. For further reading http://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/varbinarymax-tames-blob

Comment: Blobs are certainly stored in data pages, but they aren't always stored on the same pages as the other columns.  By default blobs <8K are stored in-line with the other columns, and larger blobs are stored on separate data pages.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-tableoption-transact-sql  Memory-Optimized and Columnstore tables store blobs differently.

Comment: @jean, blobs are stored in data pages in all SQL Server versions. They were always stored in separate data pages in old versions whereas they can be stored in-row in modern versions depending on the size per the documentation David referenced. I didn't go much into implementation details since a layman's answer was requested.

Comment: @DanGuzman I stand corrected. Data bigger than 8k are stored in the LOB not in the **row** but you are correct it's just in another page to not mess with the balance of the pages tree structure